# Write down the HJB equation

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Suppose that we have to solve the following optimal control problem

\begin{align}
V(t,x) = \min_{\alpha}\mathbb{E} \left[\int_{0}^{T}L(t,x,\alpha)dt  + F(e^{-\beta t}X^{\alpha}_{T})\right]
\end{align}

subject to the constraint

\begin{align}
dX^{\alpha}(t) = \mu \alpha dt + \sigma \alpha dW(t)
\end{align}

where $t\in[0,T]$, the control  $\alpha\in U$ where $U$ is compact, $\mu,\sigma$ are positive constants, $L$, $F$ are real valued functions describing a running cost and a terminal payoff.

My question is how to write the HJB equation for this problem.What i have done till now

\begin{align}
V_{t} + \mu \alpha V_{x} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}\alpha^{2}V_{xx} = 0
\end{align}

i am missing something.

Comment: Anyone ? I think i am half way there? Is thw above correct?